# Eagerly asking the user for access

Tags: android, oauth, permissions

I have an app that does something[1] that causes Android to pop a warning in the notifications bar asking the user something like:

> Permission request
>   xxx@gmail.com
>
> These apps want access to your Google account from now on
>
> - App name
>
> They are requesting permission to:
>
> - View and manage your ...
>
> <kbd>No thanks</kbd>          <kbd>Allow access</kbd>

The problem with this is that it makes the original operation fail, and then the user has to retry after clicking <kbd>Allow access</kbd>, which is annoying. Is there a way to ask the system to give the user these prompts before I actually try to perform the operation that causes them?

Obviously one way to do it would be to run the operation in question and check for exceptions, but I'm looking for a better way.

[1]more specifically, there's a class that tries to get an authentication token from an account manager